# How do I get the position of an element in a nested frame relative to the viewport with jquery?

Tags: jquery, position, frame

I have a web page consisting of several frames and sub frames and would like to know the position of an element in one of the sub frames **relative to the viewport**.

**Example**

Let's assume the following frame layout:

```
|----------------------|
|Frame A    | Frame B  |
|           |          |
------------------------
|Frame C    | Frame D  |
|           | #myDiv   |
------------------------
```

I have four frames **A,B,C,D** and in frame **D** there is an element **#myDiv**. I know that I can use jQuery's *offset()* method to get the element's position relative to the document, in my case the document of frame $D$. However, what I would like to have is the position of **#myDiv** relative to the upper left corner of the whole viewport.

Does anybody have a good solution for that? I spent some time on Stackoverflow reading answers such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714628/jquery-getting-location-of-element-relative-to-window) but none of the proposed solutions seems to work in the situation described above.

Does anybody know of a good solution for this?

Comment: Offset of frame + offset of #myDiv.

Comment: @jlareau How do I get the offset of the frame from inside the frame?

Comment: Can't tell you since no sane person would ever use iframes.

Comment: @jlareau It's a legacy application dating back from 2000.