# How to get absolute coordinates of document with JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how can i get the absolute screen coordinates of the html/body?
I found all those window.screenTop, screenLeft, outerheight/innerHeight - but thats not the solution.

**EDIT: I updated the image to clarify what I need!**

[image]

Comment: You can use JQuery `scrollLeft` and `scrollTop`functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714628/jquery-get-the-location-of-an-element-relative-to-window

Comment: Thanks so far, but unfortunately that doesnt help.
I made a new image to make more clear what i need!

Comment: The DOM works in the context of the browser. I'm pretty sure you can't get the screen offset in the desktop from JavaScript. Please correct me if I'm wrong on that!

Comment: That is my impression as well, I think I would have found it if it was possible - but better ask of course

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this (taking some assumptions):

```
//this is the border width of the OS window.
var border= (window.outerWidth-window.innerWidth)/2; 

//Assuming the window border is homogeneous and there is nothing in
// the bottom of the window (firebug or something like that)
var menuHeight=(window.outerHeight-window.innerHeight)-border*2;

var absX=window.screenX + border;
var absY=window.screenY+border+menuHeight;
```

Comment: Nifty! A workaround i can live with! ;)
Thanks, much appreciated!

Comment: Great  Answer! Note to readers: the `outer` values may be in real pixels, while the `inner` ones may be in "CCS pixel".

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
window.screenX
```

and

```
window.screenY
```

Note that screenY does not take into account address bar bookmarks bar etc at the top of the browser

Edit:

You may be able to use (window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight) to get the additional offset:

```
window.screenY + window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight
```

But this assumes you do not have any toolbars at the bottom of the browser (will break if you have docked devtools open)

Comment: unfortunately that returns 0/0

Answer (score 0):

Just get body element:

```
var $body = $(this.ie6 ? document.body : document);
```

And use this properties: $body.width(), $body.height()

Also to get the window dimensions

```
var $window = $(window);
var wWidth  = $window.width();
var wHeight = $window.height();
```

**UPDATED**
Try to use this: [Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect)

```
var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
console.log(rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, rect.left);
```

Comment: that doesnt help either, because it is unclear where the body is inside the window. I can get the top left position of the browser and the innerHeight/Width, but I need the offset!

Comment: Try to use this: Element.getBoundingClientRect()

Comment: top/left on the body is always 0/0