# How to determine offset of an element

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, window, offset, popover

I want to determine my ScreenViewport and then position of an element. And want to see if its present in 20% of the bottom of the window, or 20% top of the window.

I have two questions. **First** when I calculate viewport it returns `339` whereas the element offset returns `763`. How is element's offset greater than the viewport?

**Second** I want to know how can I get the 20% bottom and 20% top of the screen so I can match the offset with them

```
placement: function (context, source) {
        var windowpos = $(window).height();  //339
        var position = $(source).offset(); //top: 763

        if(position.top < 20% of bottom of windowpos) {
        return "bottom";
        }

        return "auto right";
}
```

Comment: The `.offset()` method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element relative to the *document* and not window/viewport. Check by viewing `$(document).height()`

Comment: @ShaunakD but if I want to get the position of my element inside viewport, how would I get it? Any idea?

Comment: Check if this works http://stackoverflow.com/a/31408076/3639582