# Dynamic Tooltip top margin for Profilecard similar to twitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Ok I want to create a Profilecard aka tooltip simiar to how twitter uses when you hover over a user's name. This will be on a timeline similar to twitter or Facebook. A container appears with a pic, background pic and users info. I only want to create one container in my html code and fill that container with users' info using php every time you hover over that user's name. **The key here is only creating one html element to reuse over and over**, then using css absolute position with a top margin and left margin to position the Profile card under the user's name. Of course I will be doing this using Jquery along with ajax loading the users info.

My problem and question is how do I tell Jquery what my top margin should be, since each user's name will be a different length away from top of the timeline.

[image: Profilecard aka tooltip example]

Comment: Please share your code so we could examine the problem properly.

Comment: This could be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714628/jquery-get-the-location-of-an-element-relative-to-window