# Align UL with grandparent UL

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have been trying to get this to work for a while with no success.

I have a multi-level navigation and I would like to align all child UL's with is main parent/grandparent UL.

right now the structure is something like this:

```html
<ul class="first-menu">
      <li class="has-children">
        <a href="#">Page 1
          <span class="arrow arrow-down"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="submenu first-submenu">
          <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
          <li class="has-children">
            <a href="#">Menu 2
              <span class="arrow arrow-down"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="submenu second-submenu">
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 6</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 7</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="has-children">
            <a href="#">Menu3
              <span class="arrow arrow-down"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="submenu second-submenu">
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 6</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 7</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="has-children">
            <a href="#">Menu 4
              <span class="arrow arrow-down"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="submenu second-submenu">
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 6</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 7</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="has-children">
            <a href="#">Menu 5
              <span class="arrow arrow-down"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="submenu second-submenu">
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 6</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 7</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="has-children">
            <a href="#">Menu 6
              <span class="arrow arrow-down"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="submenu second-submenu">
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 6</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 7</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="has-children">
            <a href="#">Menu 7
              <span class="arrow arrow-down"></span>
            </a>
            </li>
          <li class="has-children">
            <a href="#">Menu 8
              <span class="arrow arrow-down"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="submenu second-submenu">
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 6</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 7</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="has-children">
        <a href="#">Page 2
          <span class="arrow arrow-down"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="submenu first-submenu">
          <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu 6</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu 7</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="has-children">
        <a href="#">Page 3
          <span class="arrow arrow-down"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="submenu first-submenu" value="hide/show">
          <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
    </ul>
```

so, I have it setup so the second submenu shows on hover, I was able to get the second-submenu size to its grandparent UL with this:

```
 $('.first-menu').each(function(){
          $(this).find('ul.second-submenu')
          .css('min-height', $(this).outerHeight(true));
     });
```

and its position is set to absolute, top: 0 , and left: 100%, display: inline-block ...

but I would like to align all the second-submenu uls with the grandparent ul up top.

right now I have:

[image]

But, I would like to get something like this:

[image]

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Post your CSS please.

Comment: did you checked [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714628/jquery-get-the-location-of-an-element-relative-to-window)? I would suggest `vertical-align: top;` for your submenu

Comment: I apologize, just got it to work! As I was posting the CSS for @MichaelCoker, I realized that I had flex-direction: column there ... as I deleted, it worked!

Comment: there are whole sites dedicated to menu/navigation css and approaches

Comment: @Lucky500 that's one of the reasons it's important to actually reproduce the problem in the post. When you're re-constructing it, half the time you'll figure out or see whatever it was you missed. glad you got it!

Comment: I was trying to save sometime, but you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here your main problem is the CSS part where the relative parent you are using to position the submenu, you don't need the JS part and you can get your result if you just avoid the `relative` be on the `li` and just ensure you have it on the main `ul`, check this snippet:

```css
.first-menu {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 150px;
  background: orange;
}

.submenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: orange;
}

.has-children:hover>.submenu {
  display: block;
}
li:hover {
  background:green;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none
}

li {
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: tomato
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<ul class="first-menu">
  <li class="has-children">
    <a href="#">Page 1
          <span class="arrow arrow-down"></span>
        </a>
    <ul class="submenu first-submenu">
      <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li class="has-children">
        <a href="#">Menu 2
              <span class="arrow arrow-down"></span>
            </a>
        <ul class="submenu second-submenu">
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 6</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 7</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="has-children">
        <a href="#">Menu3
              <span class="arrow arrow-down"></span>
            </a>
        <ul class="submenu second-submenu">
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 6</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 7</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="has-children">
        <a href="#">Menu 4
              <span class="arrow arrow-down"></span>
            </a>
        <ul class="submenu second-submenu">
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 6</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 7</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="has-children">
    <a href="#">Page 2
          <span class="arrow arrow-down"></span>
        </a>
    <ul class="submenu first-submenu">
      <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

#### Note:

Here is a snippet with relative position on the li element so you can see how this works wrong like your actual screenshots:

```css
.first-menu {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 150px;
  background: orange;
}

.submenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: orange;
}

.has-children:hover>.submenu {
  display: block;
}

li:hover {
  background: green;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none
}

li {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: tomato
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<ul class="first-menu">
  <li class="has-children">
    <a href="#">Page 1
          <span class="arrow arrow-down"></span>
        </a>
    <ul class="submenu first-submenu">
      <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li class="has-children">
        <a href="#">Menu 2
              <span class="arrow arrow-down"></span>
            </a>
        <ul class="submenu second-submenu">
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 6</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 7</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="has-children">
        <a href="#">Menu3
              <span class="arrow arrow-down"></span>
            </a>
        <ul class="submenu second-submenu">
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 6</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 7</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="has-children">
        <a href="#">Menu 4
              <span class="arrow arrow-down"></span>
            </a>
        <ul class="submenu second-submenu">
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 6</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 7</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="has-children">
    <a href="#">Page 2
          <span class="arrow arrow-down"></span>
        </a>
    <ul class="submenu first-submenu">
      <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for this Dani!

Comment: Hey @DaniP, upon further inspecting, you are right. the issue was the position: relative on my LI. And I did remove the JS, and still works fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to help U @Lucky500