# javascript get scroll of child div

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a structure something like this:

```
<div>

    <div id="scrollID" style="height:100px;">
         content here
    </div>

</div>

<script>
document.getElementById("myDIV").addEventListener("touchstart", myFunction);
function myFunction() {
    // want to get my position
}
</script>
```

I want to get the distance from top, when user start scrolling (actually touching in mobile). My final purose is implementing pull to refresh for child `div`.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you taken a look at this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714628/jquery-get-the-location-of-an-element-relative-to-window

Comment: This [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/sjovanovic/xpull) is designed for mobile pull to refresh of a child div: [xpull](https://github.com/sjovanovic/xpull)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following.

```
<div>

    <div id="scrollID" style="height:100px;" onscroll="myFunction();">
         content here
    </div>

</div>

<script>
document.getElementById("myDIV").addEventListener("touchstart", myFunction);
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("scrollID").scrollTop;
    // want to get my position
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I get position from bottom? `document.getElementById("scrollID").scrollbottom` gives me undefined.

Comment: @vahidnajafi something like this I believe should work  `document.getElementById("scrollId").scrollHeight - document.getElementById("scrollID").scrollTop` you might to also subtract the box height this should really be another question.